# Make a LINQ select O(n), selecting just one element

Tags: c#, performance, linq

So, I'm selecting just one element in a LINQ query (`cars` is of type `Car[]`):

```
Car selectedCar = (
    from x
    in cars
    where x.Location * direction > location * direction
    orderby x.Location * direction
    select x)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is basically an O(n log n) operation (because of `orderby`). I'm okay with taking a ~30% performance hit by using LINQ, but I'm not okay with making it O(n log n) when it could very easily be O(n) with a loop. Is there a way to preserve LINQ, but reduce the order of operation?

Comment: Why use LINQ if you can do this faster by using a loop?

Comment: since you want only one element you could use min function

Comment: [MinBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Because I'm okay taking a performance hit, just not an order-of-operation hit.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen `Min` only returns the minimum value, not the item itself.

Comment: @I4V Perfect. Make that into an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) should do the trick:

```
Car selectedCar = cars
 .Where(x => x.Location * direction > location * direction)
 .Aggregate((a, b) => (a.Location * direction < b.Location * direction) ? a : b);
```

I haven't checked if this code actually works, so beware.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Car selectedCar = cars.Where(x=>x.Location * direction > location * direction).Min(x=>x.Location * direction);
```

Comment: But this would return min *value*, not car as in question. You need something like [MinBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs)

Comment: Why would you need to order items if you're choosing min value?